# How to manage sessions in Realm Mobile Platform?

Tags: swift, swift3, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I was trying to make an iOS app with real-time collaboration using Realm Mobile Platform (Swift 3) and got stuck with lack of docs and examples. At the moment I have user authentication through realm object server. I can sync data between server and **all** users. Now I want **two** users to connect within a **session**, and then to sync data between them like it was done in their drawing demo (watch the video on https://realm.io )

Comment: Could you try and add some code / further detail on what you've tried so far to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm Mobile Platform doesn't support sharing the data between different users yet. Partially resolved by this PR https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/4275.

So for now, you should share **one** `SyncUser` between multiple people to share session like a draw app demo.